# Lua ""==true equals ""==false

Tags: lua

I'm having trouble understanding how the expressions `""==true` and `""==false` both evaluate to `false`.

Trying the following in the lua interpreter and ilua result in the same output:

```
> =""==true
false
> =""==false
false
```

Or executing the following:

```
print(""==true)
print(""==false)
print(""==nil)
```

Outputs

```
Lua 5.1.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
false
false
false
>
```

Another example:

```
> =""~=true
true
> =""==false
false
```

When the following code is run:

```
if "" then -- if ""==true
    print "was true"
end 

if not "" then -- if ""==false
    print "was not true"
end
```

The output is (seemingly inconsistently)

```
Lua 5.1.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
was true
>
```

As expected per the Lua FAQ which states

> C-like languages regard 0 as equivalent to false, but this is not true
>   for Lua. Only an explicit false or nil are equivalent to false. When
>   in doubt, make the condition explicit, e.g. if val == nil then ... end
>   unless the value is actually boolean.

How can a value be *not* equal to `true`,`false` or `nill`?

Comment: Well, it seems just like `""` is an empty String. So, it is not `true`, not `false` and neither `nill`.

Comment: I don't see why it should?

Comment: I think the problem is I've assumed strings would have truthy/falsy values.

Comment: @HennyH, but you quoted the documentation that says they do not.  So why are you still surprised by it?

Comment: By the way @HennyH, you're using Python usually, right? `>>> ""==True
False
>>> ""==False
False
>>> ""==None
False` :)

Comment: @catwell yeah, I was confused why in an `if` statement it would be `true`, (as it turns out, it just isn't false or nil) but not when doing a comparison.

Comment: @catwell in python it will implicitly call __bool__/__nonzero__ in certain contexts, I had thought lua would have taken the expression and done `exp == true` which as it turns out isn't how it handles it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

All Lua values when used as Booleans evaluate to true, except nil and false. This does not mean that values that evaluate to true are *equal* to true. If you want to convert a value `v` to Boolean, use `not not v`.

Answer (score 14):

The type of `""` is string, not boolean, so it's not equal to either `true` or `false`.

To be more general, when Lua compares two values, it tests their type first, if the type mismatch, Lua thinks the two values as not equal immediately.

When used as control expression, the only false values in Lua are `false` and `nil`, everything else is evaluated as true value. Some popular confusions include the number `0`, the empty string `""`, the string `"0"`, they are all true values. Note again that `false` and `nil` are not equal because they are different types.

So back to the example, in the code

```
if "" then -- if ""==true
    print "was true"
end
```

Lua tests if `""` is `false` or `nil`, since it's neither, then Lua treats the condition as true value.

Comment: This would mean lua interprets the `if "" then` part of `if "" then print "was true" end` (which prints `was true`) differently to `"" == true`. Is there a spec. or location is the source which differentiates these contexts?

Comment: @HennyH When Lua sees `if n`, it tests if `n` is neither `false` nor `nil`. Note again though `false` and `nil` are both treated as false values, they are not equal either.

Comment: Ahh, that makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 4):

*Disclaimer: I have no experience with lua, this is an educated guess*

This is probably because "" is an empty string, so Lua probably evaluates it as a string with length of zero.  Since it's a valid object it's not going to be equal to true, false, or nil, it'll be equal to a string with length zero.

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer: the only thing I know about Lua is that I don't know anything about Lua.*

It appears that Lua treats equality comparisons using `==` and comparisons done in control structures (`if`, `while`, `for`, etc.) differently.

According to the [Lua 5.1 manual (section 2.4.4, Control Structures)](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html),

> The condition expression of a control structure can return any value.
>   Both false and nil are considered false. All values different from nil
>   and false are considered true (in particular, the number 0 and the
>   empty string are also true).

It seems like this is consistent with what you are seeing.  That is:

```
"" == false => false
"" == true => false
"" == nil => false
```

Because the comparison operator seems to be checking the type and the value.

However, if you use the variable *in a conditional in a control structure*, the behavior is slightly different.  That is,

```
if "" then
    print "Hello world!"
end
```

Will print `Hello world!`, because the empty string is different from both `nil` and `false`, and thus evaluates to a truthy value.